# how are detect() and compute() different from detectAndCompute()

Tags: python, opencv

I want to make some real time image comparison. FAST seems to perform well, but for matching purposes I have difficulties getting the keypoints described correctly.

In my testing, I tried the following code:

```
import cv2


# initiate some stuff
detector = cv2.FastFeatureDetector_create(20)
orb = cv2.ORB_create(150)
bf = cv2.BFMatcher()

# detect and compute keypoints for imageA in separate steps
imageA = cv2.imread("imageA.png", 0)
kpA = detector.detect(imageA, None)
kpA_computed, desA = orb.compute(imageA, kpA)
drawAkp = cv2.drawKeypoints(imageA, kpA_computed, None, flags=cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)

# detect and compute keypoints for imageB in 1 step
imageB = cv2.imread("imageB.png", 0)
kpB_computed, desB = orb.detectAndCompute(imageB, None)
drawBkp = cv2.drawKeypoints(imageB, kpB_computed, None, flags=cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)

# these shouldn't be that different from one another
cv2.imshow("A", drawAkp)
cv2.imshow("B", drawBkp)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

For some reason, the keypoints in imageA are not "rich" at all.
[image: drawAkp and drawBkp side to side]

I understand that the 2 images are using different algorithms for the keypoints detection, but I expected that imageA will have the sizes and orientations included after the compute()
I think understanding the reason behind that will help me with my matching problems.

Comment: If you compare keypoints detected by FAST and ORB (by separately performing detect and compute steps for orb), you can see ORB points store a valid "angle" value whereas all FAST points have -1 angle value. I thought ORB was using a FAST detector, but while searching for this problem I found out that it also performs additional steps on top of FAST detector.

Comment: You can read about ORB detector, but I will also leave these two questions here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56241536/opencv-fastbrief-how-to-draw-keypoints-with-drawmatchesflagsdraw-rich-keyp (in this question answerer claims that FAST detector does not store additional values that are necessary for a rich point), https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51195152/orb-vs-fast-detectors (in this question answerer explains FAST and ORB detectors are not identical, also comments).

Comment: Thank you for the links. After reading them and going to the tutorials one more time, now I understand that compute() defines the descriptors - the regions where the keypoints belong, but doesn't add new properties to the keypoints. That is probably the reason why FAST is faster - angle, octave and the other parameters are more computationally intensive, FAST simply skips those